# How do I insert VS Code snippet instead of replacing text

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm using a snippet for HTML that inserts "target="_blank", but it also replaces additional characters of text/code instead of just inserting.

```
"target": {
    "prefix": "tg",
    "body": "target=\"_blank\""
},
```

Here's the code that I start with:

```
<a href="URL.com">LINK</a>
```

I place the cursur before the closing bracket and here's what I expect:

```
<a href="URL.com" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```

But this is what results:

```
<a href="URL.com" target="_blank"LINK</a>
```

It replaces the closing bracket. I am not selecting the closing bracket when I insert the snippet, so I'm not sure why it replaces that character.

Thanks.

Comment: That snippet is working fine, did you try with the Insert Key on/off?

Comment: A not-brainer solution is to type ````tg```` providing a space before ````>````. Otherwise it can't tell ````tg```` & ````>```` apart.

Comment: It works perfectly for me as is.

Comment: I have the same behavior on some snippets too and made an issue for it https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96983

Comment: It's bizarre because it's intermittent and the main reason why it's frustrating. Like Sapinder recommends, I can easily train myself to add a single space before I use the snippet. However, because sometimes it works as expected (as it did for Mark), I'm having manually check. I'm trying to figure out what causes the behaviour but so far, no luck. Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: rioV8, yes that sounds like the exact same issue!